# Always true if entity framework

Tags: c#

I have simple query. I want to get rows that don't have corresponding row in other table or if it have then SubField has to be false.

```
var list = ctx.Product.Where(p => p.Field == null || p.Field.SubField == false)
```

But with this query I always get all rows doesn't matter if p.Field is null. Even if I set second condition to p.Field.SubField== true I also get all rows.

I created simple MessageBoxes to see result:

```
MessageBox.Show((c.Field== null).ToString());
result = true;

MessageBox.Show((c.Field.SubField == false).ToString());
result = object is not set exception

MessageBox.Show((c.Field == null || c.Field.SubField == false).ToString());
result = true;
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Dumb question, but do you actually have `Product`s that have `Field`s with `SubField==true`?  There's nothing obviously wrong with your query.

Comment: The Framework doesn't lie.

Comment: You're checking for SubField == false and it's giving you an exception saying it isn't set.  It looks like the SubField object could be null.

Comment: @nik0lias that'll be because `Field` is `null` (per the check above).

Comment: Hmmm now I am thinking and I think that Field == null will be enough. It will work like that: I list all rows with Field == null. Make some calculation and then save calculation to different table. If something goes wrong program will not save any data to database.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of C# short-cutting the query for you. When `p.Field == null` evaluates to `true`, there is no point attempting to look at the second part as it is part of an `or` expression. Consider this variation of your code, note that when `Field` is null, `Console.WriteLine` does not execute:

Setup:

```
public class Product
{
    public Field Field { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public bool SubField { get; set; }
}

private bool GetSubField(Product product)
{
    Console.WriteLine("GetSubField");
    return product.Field.SubField;
}
```

Example execution:

```
var products = new List<Product>
{
    new Product { Field = null }
};

var list = products.Where(p => p.Field == null || GetSubField(p) == false);
```